# Install OpenSSH on Drobo 5N

Tags: drobo

The DroboPorts site says that it is possible to install apps onto the Drobo 5N, but I understand the Drobo 5N only supports Copy and Plex right now and cannot install other apps.

Could someone please advise how I can get SSH installed on a Drobo 5N? Cannot find relevant instructions anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this site](https://annvix.com/blog/setting-up-a-drobo-5n) it should be possible and it has some instructions based on the [Drobo-specific OpenSSH source code](https://github.com/droboports/openssh) provided by [DroboPorts](http://www.droboports.com):

> Install [OpenSHH](https://github.com/droboports/openssh). This will allow you to log remotely into the
>   Drobo unit. A few things to note:
>
> 1. You will need to copy the `openssh.tgz` to the DroboApps share and then reboot, at which point OpenSHH will get installed and will start.
> 2. Any users defined will by default have access via SSH to the Drobo
> 3. Root has access with the default password `root` (please please please change this ASAP!)
> 4. The defined administrator user’s username is `Admin`, not `admin`.

Answer (score 0):

> **Connect to your Drobo**
>
> You can quickly connect to your Drobo:
>
> 1. Look up the IP address of your Drobo device using Drobo Dashboard You can find the Network Information under the Status section of the
>      dashboard for your device.
> 2. open PuTTY
> 3. enter the connection details `root@<ip-address>`
> 4. when prompted use the password "root" to authenticate
>
> You should now be logged-in and the PuTTY window should look like
>   this:
>
> [image]
>
> **Change the default password**
>
> It's good practice to change publicly known default passwords as soon
>   as possible. Sure, it's unlikely that anyone will connect to your
>   network, stumble across your Drobo, connect, and do Evil Things™ but
>   why take the risk.
>
> It's also a good way to give an example of using the SSH session.
>
> Simply type `passwd`, press Enter and follow the prompts. You won't
>   see any output when you're typing your new password; you don't know
>   how many spycams have been installed while you were at work during the
>   day.
>
> **Saving an SSH session**
>
> If you have configured your home router to assign a fixed IP address
>   to your Drobo you might want to save the session in PuTTY so that you
>   don't need to type the username and destination every time you want to
>   reconnect.
>
> Open the menu by clicking on the icon in the top left of the PuTTY
>   window, and choose New Session.
>
> 1. enter the connection details as before ( `root@<ip-address>`)
> 2. In the text input field for Saved Sessions enter a name to call the session ('MyDrobo')
> 3. click 'Save'

Please refer to this guide for more information - http://blog.chisel.pm/2014/03/how-to-ssh-onto-drobo-5n-from-microsoft.html

Comment: Please read [How to reference material written by others](http://superuser.com/help/referencing). You need to quote correctly. Please read [Markdown help](https://superuser.com/editing-help). I've done this for you but please take note for future answers.

Comment: You might also want to think about adding the remaining images to your answer. I added the one explicitly referred to otherwise the text didn't make sense. ("should look like this" with no image)